# How to setTotalPaid() and setTotalDue() manually after order success

Tags: magento-1.9, sales

I want to update order grand total, total paid amount and total due amount after order succes.

For this I have added a event `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` in my custom module and my observer function has code as below :

```
...
$order->setGrandTotal($some_amount);
$order->setBaseGrandTotal($some_amount);
$order->setTotalDue($some_amount);
$order->setBaseTotalDue($some_amount);
$order->setTotalpaid($some_amount);
$order->setBaseTotalpaid($some_amount);
$order->save();
...
```

This code update order grand total but `total_paid` and `total_due` amount not update by this.

Is it possible to update manually `total_paid` and `total_due` amount?

Is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Below code working for me.

```
$order->setGrandTotal($some_amount);
$order->setBaseGrandTotal($some_amount);
$order->setTotalPaid($some_amount);
$order->setBaseTotalPaid($some_amount);
$order->save();
```